# What is Oversee Turing v1.0.0?

Tags: apache2

System Info:
Windows 7 64-bit
VirtualBox 4.2.18
Ubuntu 12.04 Guest
Apache 2 installed and running

Running HEAD / HTTP/1.0 on terminal returns server as Oversee Turing v1.0.0

Why is the server identifying itself as Oversee Turing?

There doesn't seem to be much information online except for web server stats sites.

I was wondering if there is more background info on this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not querying your local server for its HEAD response. The servers you are querying is your local filesystem, `file:/`, for your first argument and `http.com` for your 2nd argument. So no worries, your Apache is not identifying itself as `Oversee Turing` unless you have told it to do so. Since you give two paths, do you get two responses.

*It exist a lot of ways to check headers, and since that is not the question will i not cover it.*

**For a in depth explanation:**

First, when you are giving `/` as the path for HEAD is it considered a local absolute path pointing to your filesystem root and will be expanded to `file:/`.

Second, `HTTP/1.0` is considered another absolute path. To understand how argument is interpreted, we have to take a closer look in the source beneath. But summed up is the  `HEAD` command pointing to a `perl` script. This perl script make use of `uf_uri`, a function from `/usr/share/perl5/URI/Heuristic.pm` to determine and return a full `URI` from a user friendly `URI`. That is done with running the function `uf_uristr`.

`uf_uristr` will match `# no scheme specified` at line 179 and will add schema to be `http` further will it expand the guess maps with the domain endings, on line 209+210 will it add `.com`. The different domain-endings will be tested in the for at line 215. The test will be done with `gethostbyname("$guess.")` and will set the `$host` to be the current `$guess` and exit the for loop if it gets a working result.

Then it will craft the `URI` it will return to the initial perl script on line 226;

`$_ = "$scheme://$host$_";`

```
$scheme = http
$host = http.com
$_ = /1.0
```

so the final $_ will be `http://http.com/1.0`

**Source**

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/HEAD 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Nov 23  2011 /usr/bin/HEAD -> lwp-request

$ file /usr/bin/lwp-request 
/usr/bin/lwp-request: a /usr/bin/perl -w script, ASCII text executable
```

Notice `uf_uri`:

```
vim +196 /usr/bin/lwp-request +"sp +440 /usr/bin/lwp-request"
```

`uf_uri` calls `uf_uristr` in `/usr/share/perl5/URI/Heuristic.pm` that is a part of the `liburi-perl` package.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this myself on my server. I found this article:

http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/win4n6/conversations/topics/3003

Bottom line, it is just an **Alias**, maybe related to someone from [oversee.net](http://www.oversee.net). To get your server version, just use the basic `httpd -v` modifier.